# Facebook Granted Permissions Page Blank

Tags: ios, facebook-login

After my app is redirected to an in app safari page, and I grant the permissions I have requested (email and public profile) I get a blank page with no errors or buttons for me to press.  If I press done to dismiss the controller, this counts as isCancelled.  I would post a picture but I don't have the reputation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: give me pic on group http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family

Comment: i think you forgot to set URL scheme or forgot to implement delegate method openUrl:sourceApplication ... in AppDelegate